# Mysqldump with no INSERT and TAB instead of commas

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and mysqldump to get some data from a table with blobs. My client is using mysqldump on his local machine and getting a much different result than when I run it through PHP using shell_exec(). These are the issues:

1) Columns are separated by , instead of TAB. The doc says TAB is default, and yet its using commas..

2) Blobs are enclosed by ' (quotes)

3) The local mysqldump is outputting TAB and LF chars which are escaped with \ . My PHP mysqldump seems to replace the TAB and LF chars with "\n" and "\r" for some reason

I've gone through the doc and tried to make use of any mysqldump options I can but there doesn't seem to be enough.

```
$out = shell_exec('mysqldump  --default-character-set=utf8 --no-create-info --compact --user=xxx--password=xxx--host=xxx.xxx.com db table');
echo $out;
```

Any help appreciated..

Comment: are you on windows and he is on linux by any chance?

Comment: He is on Win and our webhost is linux (debian)

Answer (score 0):

The differences can be due to different versions of mysqldump as well as to linux vs windows for the line endings (CrLF on Windows and LF on Linux).
All those can be controlled by command line options.
run mysqldump -? to get the options, here are the ones relevant to your question:

```html
--lines-terminated-by=name
                      Lines in the output file are terminated by the given
                      string.
--fields-terminated-by=name
                      Fields in the output file are terminated by the given
                      string.
  --fields-enclosed-by=name
                      Fields in the output file are enclosed by the given
                      character.
  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=name
                      Fields in the output file are optionally enclosed by the
                      given character.
  --fields-escaped-by=name
                      Fields in the output file are escaped by the given
                      character.
```

also note that there is an option for TAB delimited output but this only works if mysqldump and mysqld are on the same server

```
-T, --tab=name      Create tab-separated textfile for each table to given
                  path. (Create .sql and .txt files.) NOTE: This only works
                  if mysqldump is run on the same machine as the mysqld
                  server.
```

Comment: Yeah, if I use any of those I get no result so I guess that they are not on the same server.